# Any answer, change integrals by fubini's theorem?

Tags: calculus

Can we use fubini here :
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$ $$=$$ $$\int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} dtdx$$
so if we can use fubini because here The symbol t is a dummy integration variable and i think it cannot appear as an integration limit of the outer integral

Answer (score 1):

The equality you've written is not correct.

Here one may just start to integrate with respect to $x$, there is no need to use Fubini's theorem. You have
$$
\int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx=\int_{0}^{1/t}x^{-p+1}dx=-\frac1{(p-2)}\frac1{t^{-p+2}},\qquad p<2,
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|\ln t|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}{\rm{d}}x\:{\rm{d}}t&=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|\ln t|^p}{|1-t|^p} \frac1{t^{-p+2}} \:{\rm{d}}t
\\\\&=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln^p t}{(t-1)^p} \frac1{t^{-p+2}} \:{\rm{d}}t.
\end{align}
$$ The latter integral is **convergent** since, near $t=1^+$, we have
$$
\frac{\ln^p t}{(t-1)^p} \frac1{t^{-p+2}} \sim \left(\frac{\ln t}{t-1}\right)^p \sim 1,
$$ and as  $t\to+\infty$, we have
$$
\frac{\ln^p t}{(t-1)^p} \frac1{t^{-p+2}} \sim \frac{\ln^p t}{t^2}.
$$